# Error while installing gdb

Tags: xcode, homebrew, big-sur, apple-silicon

Good morning everyone, these days I'm trying to install gdb on MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3, and then use it in Eclipse. I have Xcode and Homebrew configured correctly. I have tried several methods but none of them works. Here are the errors I have encountered:

```
brew install gdb
Error: gdb: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
brew install --build-from-source gdb
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.
```

---

```
brew install --build-from-source gdb
Download, ecc...
../configure --enable-targets=all --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdb/10.1_1 --disable-debug --disable-dependency-tracking
make
make install-gdb maybe-install-gdbserver
Error: Empty installation
```

I also tried downloading the tar.gz and tar.xz files but the error I get is always this:

```
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-target'
```

In case it helps, I'll leave you the output of the "brew doctor" command:

```
Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/ansidecl.h
  /usr/local/include/bfd.h
  /usr/local/include/bfd_stdint.h
  /usr/local/include/bfdlink.h
  /usr/local/include/ctf-api.h
  /usr/local/include/ctf.h
  /usr/local/include/diagnostics.h
  /usr/local/include/dis-asm.h
  /usr/local/include/plugin-api.h
  /usr/local/include/symcat.h
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Is this on an Intel or an M1 Mac?

Comment: I'm using a Mac with M1

Comment: The most recent version of GDB was released Oct 24th. Most likely it doesn't support the M1 chip yet so building it for one will fail.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for letting me know. What would you recommend I do at this point?

Comment: Do you have a specific need for `gdb` that would not be satisfied by `lldb`?

Comment: No, no special needs. The only problem I'm having is that when I start debugging in Eclipse, even though I set the debugger to use "LLDB-MI debug process launcher", it keeps telling me: "Could not determine GDB version using command: /usr/bin/lldb --version". That's why I wanted to install gdb.

Comment: I don't use Eclipse but you may find these links helpful: (1) https://github.com/lldb-tools/lldb-mi  (2) https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3829

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try with that.