# Problem with lldb-mi and Eclipse on MacOs

Tags: eclipse

I installed lldb-mi following the [documentation](https://github.com/lldb-tools/lldb-mi). At the moment I have the executable in the directory "/usr/local/bin/lldb-mi", and when I launch it I get the following output:
[image]

I configured Eclipse for C++ to choose lldb-mi for the [debugging](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_get_the_LLDB_debugger.3F). I have no errors, but debugging doesn't start. It just seems to build, how could I fix this?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: This may not be relevant to your question at all but maybe https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415634/error-while-installing-gdb#comment582536_415634 is a useful jumping-off point

Comment: thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I have already tried that method but without solving my problem